AKS internal communication between pods
I have two apis running inside the same namespace. App workflow allows them to both communicate with each other. I have them both configured behind the same AppGW and they're both browseable. However, inside of AKS in the same namespace, i have two different results when i try to curl against their hostnames. One is throwing a 404 Host Not found. Any ideas as to what's going on here?
Appreciate any help i get.
enter image description here
built a test pod and test network connectivity to both.
